# Add CSS to specific image with alt tag using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to search for specific text in an image alt tag and add CSS to that image using jQuery. I'm using the `:contains` from jQuery, but I'm not sure if that's the best way to go about it? This is what I'm trying so far:

**jQuery**

```
var imgAlt = $("img").attr("alt");

$("imgAlt:contains('morning hike')").css("border", "5px solid black");
```

**HTML:**

```
<div>
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1584879788725-56a4b394de8d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ" alt="candles on table">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1584354012731-ba34cef5963f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ" alt="morning hike">
</div>
```

Hope that makes sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't necessarily need javascript, the selector can be created using just css attribute selectors: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

`img[alt*='morning hike'] { border: 5px solid #000 }`

We could use the same selector in your jQuery

`$("img[alt*='morning hike']").css("border", "5px solid black");`

Comment: AHHH! Yeah, ok. I was trying to look that up and I couldn't remember the specific selector in CSS. But, yeah, I'd prefer to use CSS overall. Thanks!

Comment: Oh no problem, & yes it's generally best to use css for styling. If anything I tend to add or remove a class & that way I can add what css i like to the class ( rather than cluttering the DOM with inline-styles )

Comment: Agreed. Thanks again!